# Unable to call C# method in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, jqgrid

i want to call my webmethod( C# method) in aspx page in javascript ajax call.
so in URL i can pass the Test.aspx/MyMethodName

```cs
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string Loadsites() {
    var jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstsitename);
    // test.Visible = true; return jsondata;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {        
   LoadGrid = function () {
    alert('Loading Grid data');
    jQuery("#Grid").jqGrid({           
        mtype: 'POST',
        url: 'Test.aspx/Loadsites',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        colNames: ['SiteName', 'Description' ],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'SiteName', index: 'SiteName' },
                    { name: 'Description', index: 'Description' }
        ],
        sortname: "SiteName",
        rowNum: 10,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        caption: "Site Details",
        width: "auto",
        height: "auto",
        pager: '#Pager'

    });

    jQuery("#Grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#Pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true });
 }
});
```

i tried static in method but didnt work as well

Comment: i am unable to point to that method while debugging. Is there anything i need to add or missing in that ajax call.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/how-to-call-C-Sharp-methodfunction-using-jquery-ajax/
Your method should be `static`

Comment: when i use this code calling a Controller in MVC Application it works for me. As ControllerName/MethodName in url part.

Answer (score 0):

If you place this attribute `[WebMethod]` above your method signature, you could achieve that you want.

Furthermore, you method should be defined as `static`.

Answer (score 0):

There are errors on both sides (on server side and on the client side).

On the server side you declare `string` as the result of `Loadsites` and you call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` explicitly. It's wrong. `WebMethod` is designed so that it makes conversion to JSON or XML **internally**. So one should return `object` (just `return lstsitename`;) instead of `string`. `WebMethod` will converts the results to JSON based on `contentType` of the HTTP request. If you call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` additionally then the returned data is string which contains quotes, for example `[{"myCol1": "value1"}]`. Because of JSON standards such string will be converted to JSON **once more** and the resulting data returned from the server will be like `"[{\"myCol1\": "value1\"}]"`. Conversion of correct JSON data `[{"myCol1": "value1"}]` would get *array of objects* in JavaSript on the client side. Parsing the twice converted data `"[{\"myCol1\": "value1\"}]"` will produce the *string* `'[{"myCol1": "value1"}]'` instead of array of objects.

There are some important errors on the client side too (in the JavaScript code which creates jqGrid):

- you use unknown option `dataType: "json"` instead of `datatype: "json"`. As the result jqGrid will use default value `datatype: "xml"` which is wrong.
- you use unknown option `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` instead of the usage of `ajaxGridOptions` which allows to specify Ajax options: `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" }`
- you should add `loadonce: true` option if you didn't implemented server side paging of data.
- you assign `LoadGrid` without declaring of the variable and you don't call the function inside of `$(document).ready(...);`. Instead of that you should just execute once the corresponding code which creates jqGrid and add navigator bar by calling of `navGrid`.